# Change desktop background from Terminal

Tags: command-line, desktop-background

I need to change the background of my desktop in Ubuntu 12. 04 with a command in terminal, in order to make a script with bash. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 18):

Run the following command in Terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///path/to/your/image.png
```

This will change the Desktop Background to image.png.